# Deploying a REACT and Flask app on docker

Tags: python, docker, flask

I created a react app using

```
create-react-app dummy-app
cd dummy-app
yarn build
```

After this I copied the build folder to my flask app

Here are my files
requirements.txt

```
 Flask==0.10.1
```

app.py

```py
from flask import Flask
#app = Flask(__name__)
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='./build', static_url_path='/')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')

@app.route('/healthcheck')
def healthcheck():
    return 'OK'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
COPY . /opt/service
WORKDIR /opt/service
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

I build a docker container using

```
docker build -t dummyapp:latest .
```

Then I run the docker container

```
docker run dummyapp
```

The docker container is loading, but It doesn't return the contents from react build.
If I run the same flask app using python app.py everything works fine.

Please can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please understand that a container behave like a standard system. Why don't you log into your container with a shell to try your commands and see what is failing ? If your container is already started do that with docker exec -ti [container name/tag]  [shell command] where typically youl would just run a shell like: docker exec -ti [container name/tag] sh, then try your commands, investigate the app logs and so on. To start the container that would be docker exec -ti [container name/tag] sh

Comment: @NicolasBousquet I had a small typo, the container is loading but its not serving the build of my react app. as I type this I am trying to view the logs to see if they give me more information.

Comment: What does happen?  What URL are you trying to call, and what response do you get back?  (An HTTP 404 or 500?)  If you look inside the container as @NicolasBousquet suggests, does the `build` subdirectory exist with the contents you expect?

Comment: I couldn't work out from the logs what was going wrong, then I cleared out all my docker images and containers and started the entire process from scratch and it just worked. So not really sure what I was doing wrong but its sorted now. Thanks for your help guys.