# How and where do I deploy a Flask + React web app?

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, heroku

I am building a web app with a Flask backend and a React front end, and I would now like to deploy it, buy a domain, and set it up. What is the easiest way to do this?

Here's my research:

- [This website shows how to deploy an app on Heroku](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-deploy-a-react-flask-app-47a89a5d17d9). I did this, but Heroku seems to be unavailable a lot, at least today.
- [This blog post](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-to-deploy-a-react--flask-project) seems to suggest I could create a GCE instance and run things there, though (i) it seems like a little more configuration that I'd like (ii) I would need a way to link the nginx server to my domain. I suppose the benefit is that the two apps run on the same machine?
- [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63052631/deploying-a-react-and-flask-app-on-docker) had OP redo his work and it somehow worked. I'm not sure how to deploy Docker apps online, though.

Is there an easy way to deploy to a reliable service (Google Cloud/AWS/Azure)? My code has the following structure:

```
build/                 # Result of `yarn build`
server/
    server.py          # Flask server
src/                   # React code
    Component/
        Component.js
        Component.sass
    index.css
    index.js
    ...
public/
    index.html
    # Images and other stuff.
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured out how to do this using Azure. I created an App Service, then installed the Azure Tools VS Code extension. You need to move the Python server to the root directory and rename it to `app.py` (so the `.env` is also in the root folder), and then you can right-click your App Service in VS Code (in the Azure Tools tab) and then click Deploy to Web App. Easy!

Comment: Did you have to pay for hosting it?

Comment: I created a Free-account App Service in Azure. As soon as I wanted to load a sample Python project, I clicked the CLI button, and got this message: "You have no storage mounted; to maintain storage you'll have to incur a fee." So it's impossible to create a simple free Python/React app in Azure with a very small amount of storage? Are you paying for yours?

Comment: @geneb. Yes, and I've found it's not particularly cheap either. It might actually be cheaper to use something like AWS Lightsail, now that I think about it. Within Lightsail, you can have things like Flask pre-installed and at least partially configured, and you can set a limit on price.