# How to deploy a python application located in a subfolder

Tags: azure, flask, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I have a simple python application using Flask. At this point, my python app is located in the root folder. I have an Azure Web Application running on Linux with Python 3.11 as the runtime stack. I went into the Deployment Center, setup a Local Git repository to build and deploy the site and everything worked as expected. When pushing changes to the repo, the python site is built and deployed successfully.

Moving past the "hello world" example, I reorganized the folder structure to:

- .deployment
- requirements.txt
- BackEnd

  - app.py
  - static

    - Built react files are copied here
- FrontEnd

  - React app that gets built, then copied to a subfolder under BackEnd

Based on [this help topic](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments#deploying-a-specific-aspnet-or-aspnet-core-project-file), I should be able to update the .deployment file so the BackEnd folder built and deployed. I updated it so it now looks like this:

```
[config]
project=BackEnd
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true
```

When I commit my changes, I'm getting the following output which contains the error "Could not find the .NET Core project file.

```
$ git push azure master
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 388 bytes | 388.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Deploy Async
remote: Updating branch 'master'.
remote: Updating submodules.
remote: Preparing deployment for commit id 'f20ee85ffb'.
remote: PreDeployment: context.CleanOutputPath False
remote: PreDeployment: context.OutputPath /home/site/wwwroot
remote: Repository path is /home/site/repository
remote: Running oryx build...
remote: Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
remote: You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues
remote:
remote: Oryx Version: 0.2.20230508.1, Commit: 7fe2bf39b357dd68572b438a85ca50b5ecfb4592, ReleaseTagName: 20230508.1
remote:
remote: Build Operation ID: bd15bb5515ea051f
remote: Repository Commit : f20ee85ffb260dbda3560b1ccf499cc47e6992a8
remote: OS Type           : bullseye
remote: Image Type        : githubactions
remote:
remote: Detecting platforms...
remote: Error: Could not find the .NET Core project file.
remote:
remote: Generating summary of Oryx build
remote: Parsing the build logs
remote: Found 0 issue(s)
remote:
remote: Build Summary :
remote: ===============
remote: Errors (0)
remote: Warnings (0)
remote:
remote: Deployment Failed. deployer =  deploymentPath =
```

How can I deploy a Python app when the python files are not located in the root folder?

**disclaimer**: I'm a .Net developer with very little python or react experience. I've just been tasked with helping get another dev's application deployed to Azure. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have cloned a [GitHub project](https://github.com/wangwangaze/hello-world-react-flask-app) similar to your requirement and deployed to my Azure App Service:

**Project Structure:**

[image]

**Deployment Method 1:**

**Deploy with Azure CLI with below commands:**

```
1. az login
2. az webapp up --name <web_app_name> --resource-group <rg_group_name> --os-type Linux(linux web app)
 (or)
3. az webapp up --name <web_app_name> --resource-group <rg_group_name> --os-type Windows(windows web app)
```

[image]

To check if the application is deployed properly,
`Go to App Service=>Advanced Tools=>Go=>KUDU site`:

Navigate to `site/wwwroot`:

[image]

**If it is windows App service:**

[image]

**Deployment Method 2:**

You can deploy your application with VSCode as well.

- Sign in to Azure in VSCode.
- Click on `Azure icon=>Workspace=>Select Deploy to Web App`:

[image]

The deployment status can be tracked in `output window`:

[image]

**References:**

1. [reactjs - How to deploy a Flask+React application to Azure Web Service - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63982446/how-to-deploy-a-flaskreact-application-to-azure-web-service)
2. [How and where do I deploy a Flask + React web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71975984/how-and-where-do-i-deploy-a-flask-react-web-app)